# Combining socket.io with a redux reducer

Tags: react-native, redux, socket.io

The stack - React native, socket.io, Node.js

Im developing a chat app. At this point I have a flow like that : 
User clicks "send message" -> the message is emitted by socket.io to the server -> the socket connection on the server gets the message. 
Now, from that point what I want is the message to be sent from the server to the redux reducer and then the reducer will return a new state that the frontend component will render.
How do I make the connection between the server side socket and the reducer?

The current server :

```
    const express = require("express");
    const app = express();
    const port = 3000;
    const server = require("http").createServer(app);
    let io = require("socket.io")(server);

    app.get("/", (req, res) => res.send("Hello World!"));

    io.on("connection", socket => {
      console.log("a user connected");

      socket.on("join", (name, message) => {
      console.log("chat room connected")
      });

    });

    server.listen(port, () => console.log(`listening on port ${port}!`));
```

The current reducer :

```
    const initialState = {
      chats: [

      ]
    };
    const chatsReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
      let sender = action.sender;
      let message = action.message;

      switch (action.type) {
        case SEND_MESSAGE:
          let newMessage = {
            sender: sender,
            message: message
          };

          let newState = { ...state, chats: state.chats.push(newMessage) };
          return state;

        default:
          state;
      }
      return state;
    };

    export default chatsReducer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can emit the new message from the node server like.

```
let msg = {message: 'Actual Message', sender: 'Name of sender'}
io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on('chat message', msg => {
    io.emit('chat message', msg);
  });
});
```

Then in you chat component listen the chat message event.

```
 componentDidMount() {
    this.socket = io("http://server.address:port");
    this.socket.on("chat message", msg => {
       this.props.onMessageReceivedAction (msg); // import action and will execute on message received event
   });
});
```

Then add the action :

```
export const onMessageReceivedAction = (params) => {
  return  {type: MESSAGE_RECEIVED, payload:msg};
};
```

Add message received reducer case to your reducer

```
case MESSAGE_RECEIVED:

  let newMessage = {
    sender: payload.sender,
    message: payload.message
  };

  return { ...state, chats: state.chats.push(newMessage) };
```

This will return the new state and the component props mapped to the above state will get re-rendered.

Hope this will answer your question.

Comment: Exactly what I meant. Thank u

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: What if we want to use socket connection on multiple components? do I need to use a redux middleware?

Comment: In that case, you can open the socket at parent most component, and can connect redux state(new message) to the components wherever you want. just don't forget to close the connection on unmount.